# PHP LDAP queries bring back different results every time

Tags: php, ldap

I am using PHP4 (cannot upgrade) to query around 2,000 accounts but it's bringing back different results each time I refresh the page. If I shrink the number down to around 800 the results are still different each time, if I move down to around a dozen then I get the same results each time. Please can anyone advise?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$user = "CN=Account Name,OU=Users,OU=Helpdesk,OU=Group IT,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk";
$psw = "PasswordHere";
$csv = file('AD-Managers.csv');
foreach ($csv as $line){
    $names = explode(",",$line);//explode by commas
    $managerExists = "0";
    $managerUPN = $names[4];
    $managerSearch = "userprincipalname=".$managerUPN;
    $search = "userprincipalname=".$userUPN;
    $server = "jpr-ads-01s.jpress.co.uk";
    $dn = "DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk";
    $ds=ldap_connect($server) or die("Could not connect to {$ldaphost}");
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3); 
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0); 
    if($r=ldap_bind($ds, $user , $psw)){ //using bind as I will be updating accounts once I get it working
        $sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $managerSearch);
        $data = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);

        //array shift as the first result in the array is NULL
        $daa = array_shift($data);

        foreach($data as $userData){
            if (strpos($userData["dn"], 'Google Apps') == false){//make sure it's not a contact
                $managersName = $userData["distinguishedname"][0];
                $managerExists = "1";
                break; //stop the loop if the user is found
            }
        }
    }
    ldap_close($ds);
    if($managerExists == "1"){
        echo "manager: ".$managerUPN;
        echo "<br />";
    }
else{
        echo "manager not found: ".$managerUPN;
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

sample of CSV:

```
1234567,John Smith,JOHN SMITH,john.smith@domain.co.uk,johns.manager@domain.co.uk,ABC1234,1,,,,,,,,,,,,
8901234,Jane Doe,JANE DOE,jane.doe@domain.co.uk,janes.manager@domain.co.uk,DEF7890,2,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Sample result 1:

```
manager not found: johns.manager@domain.co.uk
manager not found: janes.manager@domain.co.uk
```

But I could refresh the page instantly and get:

```
manager: johns.manager@domain.co.uk
manager: janes.manager@domain.co.uk
```

Comment: you should inspect your `{}` bracket pairs.  From what you posted:  `foreach ($csv as $line){ //stuff  } else { echo "manager not found: ".$managerUPN; echo "<br />";}`   That doesn't make sense.

Comment: thanks, tidied up code, that was because I removed some company info before posting on here and got a bracket in the wrong place

Comment: Also, you should use `===` and not `==` with [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).  "**Warning**

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function."

Comment: thanks, added the extra =, just run the script 3 times, out of 2,600 users each run returned this many users not found: 1222, 1350, 1577

Comment: I would var_dump($userData) in that else clause to see what it contains when the manager is not found.

Comment: Another suggestion: You should move the `ldap_connect`, `ldap_set_option`, and `ldap_bind` to happen before the foreach loop. Then do the `ldap_close` after the loop is over. There's a lot of extra time to re-connect and bind for each line in the CSV.

Comment: @ChadSikorra that's there as I will be adding 3 more domains when I get it working

Comment: I have added an echo for when LDAP bind fails, turns out this is the issue, does anyone know a way around this? I will be adding data to those it finds so it needs to bind

Comment: You can have multiple `$ds` instances. Just keep them in an array like: `$ds['domain1'] = ldap_connect($server);`. As far as the bind issue, what is the error message when it happens? Do a `var_dump(ldap_error($ds));` after it fails.

Comment: @ChadSikorra thanks Chad, sorry for not replying sooner, I've been off work for a week, I get the following error: `string(25) "Can't contact LDAP server"` - I cannot find what this means anywhere

Comment: Does it do that immediately or on the second or third line of the CSV? That means that for whatever reason it cannot connect to port 389 on `jpr-ads-01s.jpress.co.uk`. If it does that